# Logging with filters stopped working after upgrade to NLog 5

Tags: nlog

I'm using Nlog for years to ... log details and exceptions from an application.

The NLog.config file is unchanged for years and it looks as below

```xml
<nlog>

<targets>       
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f"
       fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" 
       layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" />
        
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fe"
       fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}_err.log"
       layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="f" >
       <filters>
          <when condition="contains('${message}','[HTTPS]')" action="Ignore"/>
          <when condition="contains('${message}','[EmailCachingHelper]')" action="Ignore"/>
       </filters>
   </logger>
       
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fe" ></logger>
</rules>

</nlog>
```

The problem is, since a while, about two weeks ago, the f log file is no longer created.
The exceptions log file, fe, *_err.log is still created ok.

In that date I updated Nlog from 4.7.15 to 5.0.0

Does anyone know what could cause this?
Is there any additional config setting I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found a breaking change in config from 4.x to 5.x

The LoggingRule Filters DefaultAction was changed from `Neutral` to `Ignore`.

This means NO output, if using dynamic filters and not already using `defaulAction="Ignore"`.

The fix was to add DefaultAction to Log

```xml
<filters defaultAction="Log">
```

which fixed the problem

Comment: See also NLog 5 Breaking change: [LoggingRule Filters DefaultAction changed to FilterResult.Ignor](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#loggingrule-filters-defaultaction-changed-to-filterresultignore)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly where I found the info. Thanks anyway